# PHP + Node - pass arguments to already running process

Tags: php, node.js

I am wondering if it is possible to pass arguments to already running Node process assuming that the process was started by php.

Is it possible? How to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is obviously not possible because the process is already running, not just Node but any process.

`process.argv` is usually read once on application start because it isn't supposed to be changed:

```
const options = process.argv.slice(2);
```

It's possible to tamper `process.argv` when Node process is debugged but this shouldn't be used in production. Also, this would require to write an app with this intention and reference `process.argv` instead of `options` everywhere.

If Node application needs to change its parameters at runtime, it should explicitly provide a way to do this (inter-process communication, as another answer mentions).

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by Estus, it is not possible to pass **arguments** to already running process.
But as per your question, you wants to use **Inter Process Communication(IPC)** which is possible.
You can refer [this link for information on IPC](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/inter-process-communication/).
Following links are also useful:
 - [PHP Inter-process communication to monitor message queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6036132/php-inter-process-communication-to-monitor-message-queue)